# pass highlighted text from text control in wxPython

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm working on building some extra functions on  spell checker for my wxPython GUI. Currently, when I check for the misspelled word against the dictionary( local dictionary) I  get back the  misspelled words  and it prints them out. now I want those words inside the text that are misspelled to be highlighted or underlined red when I get the misspelled words.  Below are the codes and when i run it it loops the misspelled words in the editor.

```
def OnCheckSpell(self, event):
    os.chdir('d:/KKSC')
    dic = getDic()
    print dic[0], dic[1], dic[2]
    text = tokenize_editor_text(self.control.GetValue())
   text = tokenize()
    # load the dictonary
    for v in dic:
       print v
        for word in text:
            if word not in dic:
                    self.control.SetDefaultStyle(wx.TextAttr(wx.BLACK))
                    self.control.AppendText(word+" ")
            else:
                     self.control.SetDefaultStyle(wx.TextAttr(wx.RED)) 
                     self.control.AppendText(word+" ")
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: The result of the for loop is the misspelled words. How can i highlight or underline the misspelled words in return?

Comment: What do you mean by "in return"? Are you looking for `wxTextCtrl::GetStyle()`?

Comment: I mean when you are trying to check the spelling for a sentence . and you write the sentence inside the editor and hen you click on spelling  I need  the editor to highlight or underline the misspelled words dynamically.

Comment: `SetStyle()` allows you to change the display style. You really need to update/rewrite your question to make it *clear* what your problem is.